# Encode Struct[] in ethers to pass to a dynamic bytes

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, bytes, encoding

I have a method in solidity:

```
function getVotesWithParams(
    address account,
    uint256 blockNumber,
    bytes memory params
) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
    return _getVotes(account, blockNumber, params);
}
```

It takes in a bytes params, that bytes params is suppose to represent a struct:

```
struct VoteOptions {
    uint24 supportOption;
    uint24 percent;
}
```

Type chain generates this struct to represent it:

```
export type VoteChoicesStruct = {
  name: PromiseOrValue<string>;
  data: PromiseOrValue<BytesLike>;
};
```

I'm creating that struct in a test like so:

```
const voteOptions: VoteOptionsStruct[] = [{ supportOption: BigNumber.from(0), percent: BigNumber.from(1000)}]
const voteData = defaultAbiCoder.encode(["bytes"], [voteOptions]);
```

When I try to encode it into bytes I get an error:

> Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value=[{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x00"},{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x03e8"}], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.7.0)

Answer (score 0):

hmm, turns out I shouldnt be passing bytes, it need to know the internal types in solidity.

```
const voteOptionsValues = voteOptions.map(o => Object.values(o));
const voteData = defaultAbiCoder.encode(["tuple(uint24,uint24)[]"], [voteOptionsValues]);
```